# What does this warning mean in PATE analysis?

Tags: python, pytorch, pysyft

Got warning while doing PATE analysis:

> Warning: May not have used enough values of l. Increase 'moments' variable and run again.

```py
from syft.frameworks.torch.differential_privacy import pate
```

```py
data_dep_eps, data_ind_eps = pate.perform_analysis(teacher_preds=preds, indices=indices, noise_eps=0.1)
print("Data Independent Epsilon:", data_ind_eps)
print("Data Dependent Epsilon:", data_dep_eps)
```

It has gone after increasing the value of the "moment" parameter in the "pate.perform_analysis" analysis function. But I want to know why this was so.

```py
data_dep_eps, data_ind_eps = pate.perform_analysis(teacher_preds=preds, indices=indices, noise_eps=0.1,moments=20)
print("Data Independent Epsilon:", data_ind_eps)
print("Data Dependent Epsilon:", data_dep_eps)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR: `perform_analysis` wants to double-check unusually small epsilon results by using more granular computation.**

The `pate.perform_analysis` function iterates through the data (technically the privacy loss random variable) and computes various epsilons.  It uses the `moments` parameter to know how granular this iteration should be.  When using the default 8 `moments`, it will compute 8 epsilons.  Then it returns the minimum of the computed epsilons, as you can see [in the source code](https://github.com/OpenMined/PySyft/blob/dev/syft/frameworks/torch/differential_privacy/pate.py#L261).

When this function returns a very small data-dependent epsilon, it could be because A) the data has a high amount of agreement, or B) the computation wasn't granular enough, and the true epsilon is higher.  When only 8 epsilons are computed, it's possible that they happened to be anomalies in the data that paint an overly-optimistic picture of the overall epsilon!  So the function sees a surprisingly small epsilon and warns you - may want to increase the `moments` variable to compute more epsilons and make sure you've found the real minimum.  If you still get the same result when you increase your `moments` parameter, your data probably has a high amount of agreement, so it truly has a small data-dependent epsilon compared to its data-independent epsilon.

Hopefully that makes sense to you at a high level.  If you want more details on the math behind this, you can check out [the research paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.05755.pdf) that inspired the source code.